# App crash before didFinishLaunchingWithOptions in ios 6

Tags: ios6, crash

It is okay if I run app on ios 7 and 8. When I run on ios 6, I got these error in my device log.

```
Job appears to have crashed: Segmentation fault: 11

Application 'UIKitApplication:com.myapp.app[0x6f3e]' exited abnormally with signal 11: Segmentation fault: 11

libMobileGestalt copySystemVersionDictionaryValue: Could not lookup ReleaseType from system version dictionary
```

I have searched through but it doesn't solve. May I know how to do?

Comment: is your sdk updated?

Comment: SDK of? Currently, I have latest xcode and base SDK is ios 8.1. Architectures and valid architecture is armv7.

Comment: This error occurs when a memory is being accessed that is no longer there. Probably a property is being accessed that is not in the memory. Have you tried using a debugger to see which variable is being accessed just before the crash.

Comment: I can't see because my app crash before appdelegate called (Didfinishlaunchingwithoptions).

Answer (score 0):

Segmentation faults are usually caused by (way) over-allocating memory. The other warnings you posted seem to support this. Does your app maybe contain a loop where it creates lots of objects without freeing them. So free the memory allocated....